# Why doesn't everyone say 'Al HaNisim for both days of Purim?

Tags: purim, shemoneh-esrei, bentching

No matter where you live, walled city or not, there is no Tahanun or LaMenatzeah on either day, you aren't allowed to fast on either day, and you can even fulfill Matanoth LaEvyonim on either day (according to some opinions, and subject to certain restrictions).

Clearly, both days are significant days to all of Klal Yisrael. Why, then, don't we all say 'Al HaNisim on both days?

Comment: BTW the custom in Sura and Pumbedita was to say Tachanun on both days of Purim.

Comment: Is that also from the Biur HaGR"A?

Comment: No. Beit Yosef there quoting Amram Gaon.

Comment: I need to get a full Tur one of these days.

Comment: Saying Al HaNisim is also a dispute in the Mishnah Brurah (I don't have time to find it now, but it's in the laws of Purim).

Comment: @ba What do you mean? What is the dispute?

Comment: @DoubleAA The Mishnah Brurah records a dispute whether to say Al HaNisim on Shushan Purim outside of a walled city. I can't find it right now, but I remember that it was in the laws of Purim rather than those of Chanukah.

Comment: @ba I don't see it in 693 which is where I would expect it to be, nor have I heard of such an opinion. (Not saying it doesn't exist, but I am surprised to hear of it.)

Answer (score 3):

The Gra (Beiur HaGra OC 693:2) explains that the only significance the 15th of Adar has to a resident of an unwalled city or the 14th of Adar has to a resident of a walled city, is that of a prohibition on fasting and eulogizing deriving from [Megillat Ta'anit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megillat_Taanit). The day is not a special holiday deserving of special liturgical mention.

Comment: Ok. Impressive find.

Answer (score 1):

The Bais Yosef 693 brings the אורחות חיים that it is assur to Lein and say al hanisim on the 15. The Bais Yosef does not know why it is assur to say al hanisim.The Bach however says it is pashut and one would have to go back and repeat.

Comment: There is an interesting Rivevos Ephraim 185:14 on that Bais Yosef.

Comment: Chelek 2 of the Rivevos.

Comment: How does this answer the question? I didn't post this for that reason.

Comment: Incidentally we lained this morning.

Comment: The laining of Purim I meant,the Bach answers the q.

Comment: The Orchot Chayim says לקרות בתורה and I don't understand why reading Vayavo Amalek would be assur. How does the Bach answer the OP's question?